# log-like distance between probability distributions

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

Given two probability density functions (PDF) $f$ and $g$, both defined over the same set $X$, there are [many ways](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance) to describe/measure the distance between them, e.g., [KL divergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence) and [Hellinger distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hellinger_distance), to name a few.

**What I'm looking for** is a distance function $d(f,g)$ that gives *an order of magnitude difference*. To be concrete, if at some area $f\sim 2\times 10^4$, $f_1 \sim 10^4$, and $f_2 \sim 10^2$, I want that $d(f,f_1) \ll d(f,f_2)$. Is there a known, statistically or probabilistically meaningful way, to do that?

I know that this question is a bit vague, but if I knew how to define such a distance function, I wouldn't be asking this question. Note that, as in the examples above, $d(\cdot, \cdot)$ doesn't have to be a metric.

Thanks

*Edit*: This has been [cross-posted](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/305919/116453) in Cross.Validated

Comment: What's wrong with the $L^\infty$ norm?

Comment: Hi @SteveHuntsman, thanks for the suggestion. In my case $d(f,f_1)=10^4 \approx d(f,f_2)$. So it doesn't "respect" order of magnitude. Furthermore, it'd be prefered for the proposed distance to have a probabilistic meaning.

Comment: @AmirSagiv- Let me recommend Deza and Deza's enclyclopedia of distances at https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-662-44342-2_14 for a place to start

Comment: What sort of probabilistically meaningful information do you hope such a distance metric will describe? Maybe I am being cynical but I can't see how it would preserve much... you can easily design distributions that are distant in your sense [up to some interpretation] but close in many other very strong ways.

Comment: What I want to know is whether for some value $X=x_0$, I have that $f(x_0)$ is at the same order of magnitude as $f_1(x_0)$, but two order of magnitudes greater than $f_2$. So, in general, it would be some integral of this kind of a measurement, over all $X=x$.

Answer (score 1):

What about the symmetric-ized KL divergence?
$$D(p,q) + D(q,p)$$

Recalling that
$$D(p,q) = \sum_x p(x) \log \left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)$$
then the $\log(p/q)$ is the order of magnitude of the ratio.

I guess I'm assuming that you're interested in the order of magnitude of the ratio rather than the absolute value.  Also, depending on what you want with the "$\ll$", you could exponentiate the distance function above.  (E.g., if we consider "1000" to be 3 orders of magnitude, do you want the value "1000" or the value "3"?  Symmetric KL gives you something more like "3".)